# Bash script for finding binomical coefficient

Tags: bash, function, shell, combinations, factorial

I am trying to generate a function for a binomial coefficient. I'm using nCk=n!/(k!(n-k)!) formula for this.

My present code is :

```
function factorial {
  typeset n=$1
  (( n < 2 )) && echo 1 && return
  echo $(( n * $(factorial $((n-1))) ))
}

function nCk {
  echo $((factorial $1/$(( factorial $2 *factorial $(($1-$2)) ))  ))
}
```

But I'm getting errors since I might be messing with the syntax.

Comment: What errors are you getting, specifically?

Comment: While easy to understand, that formula is a terrible choice for actually *computing* binomial coefficients.

Comment: You asked @chepner underneath my question so he will not have been notified (now he will :). I have added to my answer to show a better formula anyway.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

The error is in your `nCk` function:

```
nCk() {
    echo $(( $(factorial $1) / ( $(factorial $2) * $(factorial $(($1-$2))) )  ))
}
```

You need to be careful to enclose each subexpression in `$( )` so that things like the `*` are not treated as arguments to the `factorial` function. Note that I've also changed the declaration to use the more widely compatible function syntax.

As @chepner has suggested in the comments below your question, this is not the best way to go about computing the binomial coefficient. One of the reasons for this is that you need to calculate the factorial, which gets very large very fast. The highest factorial I can compute using bash is `20!`; any higher values cause integer overflow to occur:

```
$ factorial 20
2432902008176640000
$ factorial 21
-4249290049419214848
```

There are [other ways to calculate the binomial coefficient](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Binomial_coefficient#Computing_the_value_of_binomial_coefficients), which don't require a factorial. The function below implements one of them:

```
nCk2() {
    num=1
    den=1

    if (( $2 < $1 - $2 )); then
        k=$2
    else
        k=$(( $1 - $2 ))
    fi

    for ((i = 1; i <= k; ++i)); do
        ((num *= $1 + 1 - i)) && ((den *= i))
    done
    echo $((num / den))
}
```

Using this approach, the coefficient can be calculated for higher values of `n` without suffering from integer overflow. As a pleasant side effect, the function is also much faster than the original as it doesn't call a recursive function several times.

Comment: @Fenech, I wanted to thank everyone. So decided to comment at the end.
Anyway, when I try `nCk2 21 20`, I get `-1` !! Also if I use `factorial(){
echo $(seq 1 $1) | tr " " "*" | bc}` I can calculate factorial of a number > 20. But there I also get `-1` ! :(

Answer (score 1):

Try this. The problem was with calling the factorial inside the subshell.

```
function nCk {
  echo $(($(factorial $1)/$(( $(factorial $2) * $(factorial $(($1-$2))) ))  ))
}
```